# Simplify the sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

How to deal with combinatoric interpretation (or just solving it in algebraic way) when we have $(-1)^i$ factor in our sum?

Example task: 
Simplify the sum:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i} \text{ for } 0\le k \le n $$

For task without $(-1)^i$ 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k} i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i} = n \binom{2 n-1}{k-1} $$
I can write that interpretation:

- I have $n$ rabbits and $k$ slots
- Each rabbit can be in both slot of first type and second type
- slots of first type + second type = $k$
- Lets double rabbits
- I choose one rabbit as an king and it will be also a rabbit to slot of first type
- so I need to choose $2n-1$ rabbit for $k-1$ slots 
  But I don't know how to deal with $(-1)^i$

Comment: $(-1)^i$ could very much point to the inclusion-exclusion principle. Did you learn about it?

Comment: I am not sure about that in this case - yes I have learned about that but how it can be used there @Theorem?

Comment: That might be because this sum doesn't have a nice closed form? In most cases $(-1)^i $ in combinatoric problems is a definite inclusion-exclusion. Do you have context to this problem?

Comment: No, I have taken that problem from old exam from my faculty. I checked in wolfram and it claim that the result is $ -n \binom{n}{k-1} \,
   _2F_1(1-k,1-n;-k+n+2;-1)$ but I don't know what is it (checked on wiki that is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function but I haven't got that on my lecture) and how I can get this. The task was just "simplify the sum"

Comment: I can show that the answer is $\dfrac{k}{2} \left(-1\right)^{k/2} \dbinom{n}{k/2}$ when $k$ is even. Interestingly, the answer for $k$ odd seems to be $\dfrac{k+1}{2} \left(-1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)/2} \dbinom{n}{\left(k+1\right)/2}$.

Comment: Can you show how you got that? @darijgrinberg

Comment: @VirtualUser: Done. (My new argument covers both possible parities of $k$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really neat exercise. Here is the answer:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (Here, as always, $\mathbb{N}=\left\{
> 0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $.) Let $m=\left\lfloor \left(  n+1\right)
> /2\right\rfloor $. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}=m\left(
> -1\right)  ^{m}\dbinom{x}{m}
> \end{equation}
>   as polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  $.

Note that my $x$, $n$ and $k$ are your $n$, $k$ and $i$ (sorry for this -- I
am taking the lazy route and adapting your notations to mine), and I have
extended the domains for $x$ (promoted from a lowly integer to a polynomial
indeterminate) and $n$ (now any nonnegative integer).

The proof will rely on the following two facts:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $k$ be a positive integer. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> k\dbinom{x}{k}=x\dbinom{x-1}{k-1}\qquad\text{as polynomials in }
> \mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  .
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Lemma 2.* This is usually stated in the equivalent form $\dbinom
{x}{k}=\dfrac{x}{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k-1}$; in this form it is:

- the "absorption identity" (5.5) in Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, Oren
  Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, Second Edition, Addison-Wesley 1994.
- Proposition 3 in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2974977/ (except that I am
  calling the indeterminate $y$ rather than $x$ there);
- Proposition 3.26 **(e)** in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of
  algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).

You will have likely proven it by the time you have found it in these sources.
Note that this identity is the key to algebraic proofs of various identities
with "$k\dbinom{x}{k}$"s in them -- such as
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k\dbinom{n}{k}=n2^{n-1}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  -1\right)
^{k}k\dbinom{n}{k}=
\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{if }n=1;\\
0, & \text{if }n\neq1
\end{cases}
$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $\blacksquare$

> **Lemma 3.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}=
> \begin{cases}
> \left(  -1\right)  ^{n/2}\dbinom{x}{n/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even};\\
> 0, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
> \end{cases}
> \label{darij1.eq.l3.eq}
> \tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>   as polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  $.

*Proof of Lemma 3.* This is Exercise 3.22 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial
fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January
2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).
Alternatively, if $x$ is specialized to a nonnegative integer, you can use
Mike Spivey's argument at
[Alternating sum of squares of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180150/alternating-sum-of-squares-of-binomial-coefficients/180440#180440)
(which is stated for the particular case $n=x$, but can easily be adapted to
the general case -- see my comment under his post) to prove
\eqref{darij1.eq.l3.eq} combinatorially; then, use the "polynomial identity
trick" to un-specialize $x$. You can probably find lots of other approaches on
math.stackexchange. Either way, Lemma 3 is proven. $\blacksquare$

Now, we can prove Theorem 1:

*Proof of Theorem 1.* It is easy to prove Theorem 1 in the case when $n=0$.
(Indeed, in this case, both sides of the equality in question equal $0$, since
they are products in which one of the factors is $0$.) Thus, for the rest of
this proof, we WLOG assume that $n\neq0$. Hence, $n>0$. Thus,
$n-1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

We shall use the convention that $\dbinom{u}{v}=0$ whenever $v\notin
\mathbb{N}$. Thus, the recurrence of the binomial coefficients,
\begin{equation}
\dbinom{u}{v}=\dbinom{u-1}{v-1}+\dbinom{u-1}{v},
\label{darij1.pf.t1.1}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
holds not only for $v\in\left\{  1,2,3,\ldots\right\}  $ but for all
$v\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Lemma 3 (applied to $n-1$ instead of $n$) yields
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{\left(
n-1\right)  -k}  & =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n-1\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n-1\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }n-1\text{ is odd;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n-1\text{ is even}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is even;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
(since $n-1$ is odd if and only if $n$ is even, and vice versa). Substituting
$x-1$ for $x$ in this equality, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(
n-1\right)  -k}=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is even;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}
\label{darij1.pf.t1.n-1}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

If $n>1$, then $n-2\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, if $n>1$, then Lemma 3 (applied to
$n-2$ instead of $n$) yields
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{\left(
n-2\right)  -k}  & =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n-2\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n-2\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
(since $n-2$ is even if and only if $n$ is even, and since $n-2$ is odd if and
only if $n$ is odd). This equality holds not only for $n>1$, but also for
$n=1$ (since both of its sides equal $0$ in this case), and thus holds in all
cases (since we have $n\geq1$). Substituting $x-1$ for $x$ in this equality,
we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(
n-2\right)  -k}=
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The left hand side of this equality does not change if we
replace the summation sign "$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}$" by "$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}$"
(because the only new addend that we gain in this way is
$\left(  -1\right)  ^{n-1}\dbinom{x-1}{n-1}
\underbrace{\dbinom{x-1}{\left( n-2\right)  -\left(n-1\right)}}_{\substack{
= 0 \\ \text{(since $\left(n-2\right)-\left(n-1\right) = -1 \notin \mathbb{N}$)}}}
= 0$). Hence, this equality becomes
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(
n-2\right)  -k}=
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}
\label{darij1.pf.t1.n-2}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

We can split off the addend for $k=0$ from the sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(
-1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}$ (since $n\geq0$). Thus, we find
\begin{align}
& \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}
\nonumber\\
& =\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{0}0\dbinom{x}{0}\dbinom{x}{n-0}}_{=0}
+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}
\nonumber\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}}_{=-\left(  -1\right)
^{k-1}}\underbrace{k\dbinom{x}{k}}_{\substack{=x\dbinom{x-1}{k-1}\\\text{(by
Lemma 2)}}}\underbrace{\dbinom{x}{n-k}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{x-1}
{n-k-1}+\dbinom{x-1}{n-k}\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1}, applied} \\ \text{to $u = x$ and $v = n-k$)}}}\nonumber\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(  -\left(  -1\right)  ^{k-1}\right)  x\dbinom{x-1}
{k-1}\left(  \dbinom{x-1}{n-k-1}+\dbinom{x-1}{n-k}\right)  \nonumber\\
& =-x\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k-1}\dbinom{x-1}{k-1}\left(
\dbinom{x-1}{n-k-1}+\dbinom{x-1}{n-k}\right)  .
\label{darij1.pf.t1.4}
\tag{5}
\end{align}

Now,
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k-1}\dbinom{x-1}{k-1}\left(  \dbinom
{x-1}{n-k-1}+\dbinom{x-1}{n-k}\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k}\left(
\underbrace{\dbinom{x-1}{n-k-2}}_{=\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)  -k}
}+\underbrace{\dbinom{x-1}{n-k-1}}_{=\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)  -k}
}\right)  \\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have substituted }k+1\text{ for }k\text{ in the
sum}\right)  \\
& =\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k}
\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)  -k}}_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.n-2})}}}+\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(
-1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{x-1}{k}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)  -k}
}_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is even;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.n-1})}}}\\
& =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even};\\
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
+
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }n\text{ is even;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}+0, & \text{if }n\text{ is even;}\\
0+\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-2\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is even;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\dbinom{x-1}{\left(  n-1\right)
/2}, & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }
\dbinom{x-1}{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }, & \text{if
}n\text{ is even;}\\
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }
\dbinom{x-1}{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }, & \text{if
}n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\\
& \qquad\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{since }\left(  n-2\right)  /2=\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)
/2\right\rfloor \text{ when }n\text{ is even,}\\
\text{and since }\left(  n-1\right)  /2=\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)
/2\right\rfloor \text{ when }n\text{ is odd}
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor
}\dbinom{x-1}{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }.
\end{align*}
Thus, \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.4} becomes
\begin{align}
& \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}
\nonumber\\
& =-x\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k-1}\dbinom{x-1}
{k-1}\left(  \dbinom{x-1}{n-k-1}+\dbinom{x-1}{n-k}\right)  }_{=\left(
-1\right)  ^{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }\dbinom
{x-1}{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }}\nonumber\\
& =-x\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor
}\dbinom{x-1}{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor } .
\label{darij1.pf.t1.7}
\tag{6}
\end{align}

On the other hand, recall that $m=\left\lfloor \left(  n+1\right)
/2\right\rfloor $, so that $m-1=\left\lfloor \left(  n+1\right)
/2\right\rfloor -1=\left\lfloor \underbrace{\left(  n+1\right)  /2-1}
_{=\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)
/2\right\rfloor $. Also, $m=\left\lfloor \left(  n+1\right)  /2\right\rfloor
\geq1$ (since $n\geq1$ and thus $\left(  n+1\right)  /2\geq1$). Hence, $m$ is
a positive integer; thus, Lemma 2 (applied to $k=m$) yields $m\dbinom{x}
{m}=x\dbinom{x-1}{m-1}$. Now,
\begin{align*}
m\left(  -1\right)  ^{m}\dbinom{x}{m}  & =\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{m}
}_{=-\left(  -1\right)  ^{m-1}}\underbrace{m\dbinom{x}{m}}_{=x\dbinom
{x-1}{m-1}}=-\left(  -1\right)  ^{m-1}x\dbinom{x-1}{m-1}\\
& =-x\left(  -1\right)  ^{m-1}\dbinom{x-1}{m-1}=-x\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }\dbinom{x-1}{\left\lfloor
\left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor }
\end{align*}
(since $m-1=\left\lfloor \left(  n-1\right)  /2\right\rfloor $). Comparing
this with \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.7}, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{x}{n-k}=m\left(
-1\right)  ^{m}\dbinom{x}{m}.
\end{equation}
This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Darij Grinberg's answer cited a very nice combinatorial proof which I reproduce here for completeness.

Let $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We provide a combinatorial interpretation for the form $$\sum_i (-1)^in\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n}{k-i}$$ This is a signed count of ordered triples $(x,A,B)$, where $x\in [n], A\subseteq [n]\setminus \{x\},B\subseteq [n]$, and $|A|+|B|=k-1$. A triple is counted positively if $|A|$ is odd, and negatively otherwise.

Given such a triple $(x,A,B)$, we define its partner $f(x,A,B)$ as follows. Find the largest element of  $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus (A\cup \{x\}))$, and move it to the other set. If this set is empty, we leave $f$ undefined.

You can check that $f(f(x,A,B))=(x,A,B)$ whenever $f$ is defined, so that this is a well defined pairing operation. Furthermore, since $(x,A,B)$ and $f(x,A,B)$ have opposite signs, they cancel out each other in the summation, so they can be ignored.

Therefore, the only triples which contribute to the count are those for which $f$ is undefined. The only triples for which $f$ is undefined are those of the form $(x,A,A)$ and $(x,A,A\cup \{x\})$. Only one of these forms is possible, depending on the parity of $k$, and you can check that in either case the number of triples is
$$
n\binom{n-1}{\lfloor(k-1)/2\rfloor}
$$
and each exceptional triple has sign $(-1)^{\lfloor(k-1)/2\rfloor + 1}$.

Comment: Nice proof! Your set $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus (A\cup \{x\}))$ can also be written as the symmetric difference $A \triangle \left(B \setminus \left\{x\right\}\right)$. I'm saying this because it makes it a lot easier to see why your $f$ is an involution.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

$$\sum_{q=0}^k (-1)^q q {n\choose q} {n\choose k-q}$$

we have

$$\sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q q {n\choose q} {n\choose k-q}
= n \sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q {n-1\choose q-1} {n\choose k-q}
\\ = n [z^k] (1+z)^n
\sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q {n-1\choose q-1} z^q
\\ = - n [z^{k-1}] (1+z)^n
\sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^{q-1} {n-1\choose q-1} z^{q-1}.$$

Now  if $q\gt  k$ then  there is  no contribution  to the  coefficient
extractor:

$$- n [z^{k-1}] (1+z)^n
\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^{q-1} {n-1\choose q-1} z^{q-1}
\\ = - n [z^{k-1}] (1+z)^n (1-z)^{n-1}
= - n [z^{k-1}] (1+z) (1-z^2)^{n-1}
\\ = - n [z^{k-1}] (1-z^2)^{n-1}
- n [z^{k-2}] (1-z^2)^{n-1}.$$

If $k$ is odd this yields

$$-n (-1)^{(k-1)/2} {n-1\choose (k-1)/2}$$

and if it is even

$$-n (-1)^{(k-2)/2} {n-1\choose (k-2)/2}.$$

Join these to obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^{1+\lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor} \times n \times
{n-1\choose \lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor}.}$$

Comment: can you explain how you do this equality? $ n \sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q {n-1\choose q-1} {n\choose k-q}
 = n [z^k] (1+z)^n
\sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q {n-1\choose q-1} z^q $

Comment: This is [coefficient extraction for formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients) applied to ${n\choose k-q} = [z^{k-q}] (1+z)^n = [z^k] z^q (1+z)^n.$